# Pouchdb filtered replication for large database

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

Below is a service I wrote to try and sync data from my remote couchdb location to a device. However, the biggest issue I have is only wanting to retrieve data that has a `type: document` if it's within a timestamp period.

Right now, I am pretty sure it grabs EVERY document and then filters it out.

I'd like to filter it out first before it comes through because I have a LOT of documents.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish is?

```
.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", "$cordovaNetwork", "$state", function($rootScope, $q, $cordovaNetwork, $state) {

  var self = this;

  self.db = new PouchDB("IDHERE", {auto_compaction: true});

  self.remoteToDevice = function(s) {
      var remote_db = new PouchDB('https://SOMETHING@URL/IDHERE', {ajax: {timeout: 180000}});

      return self.db.replicate.from(remote_db, {

        filter: function (doc) {

            if(doc.type == 'document')
              if(doc.timestamp >= (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)-2419200)) 
                return doc;
            else return doc;
        }

      }).on('complete', function () {

        console.log("Remote to Device - Success");

      })
      .on('error', function (err) {

        console.log("Remote to Device - Error", JSON.stringify(err));
        return err;

      });

  }

}
```

---

### EDIT:

Thanks to Alexis, here is a solution I believe works

### New `remoteToDevice` filter function

```
{   
  filter: "filters/device", 
  query_params: { 
    "timestamp": (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)-2419200) 
  }
}
```

### Filter function in couchdb

```
"filters": {
    "device": "function(doc, req) { 
        if(doc.type == \"document\") { 
            if(doc.timestamp >= req.query.timestamp) return true; 
            else return false;
        } 
        else return true;  
    }"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a filter function in a design document in CouchDB.

When replicating, you will need to specify the filter name.

Full documentation here: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#filtered-replication

Comment: Thank you Alexis, I've edited my question with the solution (which I believe works) based on your link. I appreciate it; must have missed that documentation